# How to structure default nested resources?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I'm having an issue with the structure of my (currently nested) resources:

**My structure**: Posts -> Post -> Comments -> New

**My code so far**: http://jsbin.com/ewoqed/6/edit

If you click through to the post, then click `View Comments`, then click `Add Comment`, this is almost my desired effect. However, I would like this to be the UI's default behaviour, without having to click the links. So, instead of having to go to `/posts/1/comments/new`, it would just be `/posts/1`, and all the templates would be rendered from there.

I have a gut feeling that I am unnecessarily nesting my routes, but I'm not sure how to attached additional data (Comments, and a new Comment record) on the load of my PostController. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

There's [a great post on the hashrocket blog](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/ember-routing-the-when-and-why-of-nesting) about when and why to nest your routes.

Essentially, you should nest your routes when you want to nest the templates, and don't nest them if you don't want to render the templates.

Comment: Thanks Alex, this is a helpful post. Unfortunately, he doesn't cover loading everything (the post + its comments + the add comment form) on the same route, which is what I'm after.

Answer (score 3):

OK, there are two ways you can accomplish what you want:

1. You can redirect in a hook e.g. afterModel by doing this.transitionTo([childRoute])
2. You can use the [{{render}}](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_render) helper to render what you need in the parent route, and only have the parent routes

I think you want option 2, because really you don't want seperate urls, you want a post url that happens to have some other things when you view it. That's why I think you need {{render}}

There is also a  more detailed intro to the render helper [in the guides section of the website](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper).